# ef core 2.x - n:m relationship where m of different types

Tags: entity-framework-core

I need your advices on how to realise the following model in entity framework core 2.x :

I would like to implement a kind of “favorite” functionality in our software system where a user can mark customers, orders, messages etc. as “favorite” because the user is working on them right now and wants to have them in a list for quick access. Is there a possibility to realise this kind of relationship - where m can be of different types (customer, order, message …) with one relation table?

Thanks a lot for any feedback !
Best regards, 
Fabianus

Comment: Not in relational database. Which means not in EF Core (currently).

Comment: @IvanStoev - thanks !